# How to find Client Id in Groupon Affiliate account

Tags: php, groupon

I have a gruopon affiliate account.I want to get the deals for my site.
I have used this following code:

```
$.ajax({
url: 'https://api.groupon.com/v2/divisions.json?client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', 
dataType: 'jsonp',
beforeSend: function() {
    alert('ok');
},
success: function(data) {
    $('#result').html(data);
    alert(data.divisions);
},
error: function(xhr) { // if error occured
    alert("Error occured.please try again");
    alert(xhr);
},
complete: function() {
    alert('done');
}
```

});

The error I am getting is :

```
{"error":{"httpCode":401,"message":"'client_id' is invalid"}}
```

I thought the **Reporting API key** in my account is the client id,but I am having doubts now.Please help me finding the client id.